# Markdown, html and sql compatibility

Tags: sql, markdown

I have this code that collects text and/or an image and puts it in a php sql database. (the user submits this code). But how do I store markdown code in my database? And how does my user submit markdown code. For example if I want to use markdown in my html page, I want the user to be able to make their text bold or italic, but how do I include markdown in the page?